# Getting strange response on calling verifyReceipt to verify an in-app

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I am making a call to verifyReceipt to validate an in-app purchase but am getting a very strange response (the response is b)

The same code worked till some time back. But I stopped the app debugging while the trans was being verified at one point. From there on, the only response I get is **b**. I checked the code and it has nothing wrong. As I said, the same code worked till I stopped this trans mid-way.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a third-party framework or something you wrote?  AFAIK there is no `verifyReceipt` in the SDK.  You have to write PHP or other web code on your own server to talk to Apple's server in order to verify.

Comment: It is not a method in the SDK. It is the URL you call in order to verify a transaction. In the sandbox environ it is https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was an issue with Apple servers. The same request gives the correct response now, both over sandbox and the production enviorns.